# How to get a list of indexes from list of counts?

Tags: scala

Given an input sequence:

```
Array[Int] = Array(0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0)
```

I want a list that gives me indexes of each entry times, the number of times for each entry in the sequence. The output here would be:

```
Array[Int] = Array(1, 3, 3, 4)
```

There is one instance of index 1, two instances of index 3, one instance of index 4. How can write a function to do this in scala?

Here is one attempt, but I

```
val func1 = (cnt: Int, idx: Int) => Array.fill(cnt)(idx)
countarray.zipWithIndex.map(func1)

func1: (Int, Int) => Array[Int] = <function2>
<console>:132: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int) => Array[Int]
 required: ((Int, Int)) => ?
              seq_of_vectors.map(_.numNonzeros).zipWithIndex.map(func1)
```

Comment: What have you tried already? It's easier to help someone who has shown some effort. And BTW, your numbers are off. There's one instance of index 3 (the `2`).

Comment: @jwvh the 2 indicates that there should be two counts of the 3

Comment: Ah, got it. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're quite close.

```
arr.zipWithIndex.flatMap{case (rep,idx) => Array.fill(rep)(idx)}
```

Use `flatMap()` so that all the intermediate `Array`s will be flattened into one `Array` result.